# ReactNative - NativeBase - ActionSheet : Items color are white with a white background

Tags: react-native, native-base

I display an ActionSheet from native-base lib and on iOS it displays correctly but on Android the text item color is white over a white background so not visible.

Can I change the style of an ActionSheet control?

I don't know how to find the CSS affecting this.

I have React Native 0.57.1 and Native Base 2.8.1.
Thanks!

[image: Action items not visible]

Comment: Changing the color of the text seems to be a recurring issue. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2337 The poster changed their app’s text to be white so that it wasn’t visible on the actionsheet - this may be related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the text color of the whole app to black and change locally the fonts to white, no other solution!
It's not possible to change the font color of the ActionSheet control itself!

Answer (score 0):

Just use isModal false in Actions sheet

Answer (score 0):

- NativeBase does not provide a direct way to change the style of the ActionSheet component. However, you can create a custom ActionSheet component by wrapping the native-base ActionSheet with a View and applying your custom styles to the View.
- You can create a custom Item component.

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
  import { ActionSheet } from 'native-base';

  const CustomItem = ({ children, ...props }) => {
   return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.customItem} {...props}>
      <Text style={styles.customItemText}>{children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   );
  };

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   customItem: {
    backgroundColor: 'white', // Change the background color
    padding: 10,
   },
   customItemText: {
    color: 'black', // Change the text color
   },
  });

  export default CustomItem;
  ```
- Use the CustomItem component in your ActionSheet.

  ```
  import CustomItem from './CustomItem';

  // ...

  <ActionSheet
   options={options.map((option) => (
    <CustomItem key={option}>{option}</CustomItem>
   ))}
   cancelButtonIndex={CANCEL_INDEX}
   destructiveButtonIndex={DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX}
   title={title}
   onPress={onPress}
  />
  ```
- NativeBase Cheat Sheet : https://docs-v2.nativebase.io/docs/CheatSheet.html
- NativeBase Components : https://remicck.gitbooks.io/native-base-docs/content/Components.html